# Does all browser engines treat "\<" as "<" and "\>" as ">"?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, escaping

The main point to make "<" to "\<" and ">" to ">" is to make avoid below inline script:

```
<script>
   var foo = "</script><script>alert('bug');</script><script>"; // the value of foo is generated from server
</script>
```

The string value of foo is generated from server side. So, we plan to change "<" to "\<" and ">" to ">". (I know there is argument that ">" should be escaped to "& gt;", but it is not in consideration in this case.)

So, the expected result is:

```
<script>
   var foo = "\</script\>\<script\>alert('bug');\</script\>\<script\>"; // the value of foo is generated from server
</script>
```

For IE7/8 and Firefox, the HTML rendering engine will not treat **\<script\>** in javascript string as **<script>** tag, and JavaScript engine still take it as string "<script>". However, I'm not sure whether all browsers treat ">" and "\<" this way. Is this kind of standard for all browsers?

Comment: FYI, chrome and safari don't do it either

Answer (score 5):

No, your best bet is to use &gt; and &lt; for the greater than and less than signs respectively.

So you'd want something like this:

```
var foo = "&lt;/script&gt;&lt;script&gt;alert('bug');&lt;/script&gt;&lt;script&gt;";
```

Comment: Oh, I had never had such a thing happen to me before. How odd.

Comment: I check it on popular browsers:
IE5 on WinXP
IE7 
IE8
Firefox on Win
Firefox on Mac
Safari on Mac

They are treat inline "\>" as ">".